# Calculating item offset for pagination

Tags: pagination

this seems like very simple maths but somehow, my brain cant think ...

i am trying to implement pagination and will need to calculate the item offset to use in limiting my result set. i am having problems calculating what index the first item of the page should have.

eg.

```
with 1 page having 10 items

page 1 will have items 1 - 10
page 2 ............... 11 - 20
page 3 ............... 21 - 30
```

i thought of

```
offset = page * itemsPerPage + 1
```

but this will not be the case for page 1. there must be a formula for this? am using PHP/Zend_Paginator/Doctrine2 but this should be language independent

*wonder if this should be in the the maths stack exchange site*

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use `offset = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1`.

Comment: Should it not be: offset = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage

As result number 1 would never be shown otherwise?

Comment: Hi do you mean offset = (page_number - 1) * itemsPerPage;
If so won't the result generate numbers bigger than the itemsPerPage number?

Comment: I meant to answer the question while taking Jiew’s example into account. He’s obviously trying to calculate the first item number for each page; so firstItemForPage(1)=(1-1)·10+1=1, firstItemForPage(2)=(2-1)·10+1=11, and so on.

Comment: ```$offset = ($pageLimit * $page) - $pageLimit;```
I have been using the above more than a year now.
You can also try it out.

Answer (score 53):

Honestly depends.  I'm no PHP person, but I'll put both out there.  If you are pulling your records in to some form of collection (list, array, etc.) then your formula should be:

```
offset = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage
```

This is because most (again, I'm not a PHP person) arrays and lists use 0 for their first element.  If they do not use 0 for their first element and/or you're pulling from a table or something else where the IDs start at 1, then it should be:

```
offset = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1
```

I hope that's clear and helps.

Comment: "Usually" everyone is using 0 as starting point, be it PHP, javascript, etc.

Answer (score 16):

```
  start = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1
  end = totalItems

  if (itemsPerPage < totalItems) {
    end = itemsPerPage * page
    if (end > totalItems) {
      end = totalItems;
    }
  }

  // e.g. "21-30 of 193 items"
  start + '-' + end + ' of ' + totalItems + ' items'
```

Answer (score 7):

Using JS as an example, for progressive web app people...

JS arrays have the prototype method `.slice(start, end)` [overview here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it takes a start index and an end index as arguments.

I found the easiest way to calc both indexes is as follows;

**Start Index**

```
var start =  parseInt((selectedPage - 1) * resultsPerPage);
```

**End Index**

```
var end = parseInt(selectedPage * resultsPerPage);
```

**Execution**

```
var myPaginatedArray.slice(start, end);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this one is perfect and covers all scenario.

```
$offset = ($pageLimit * $page) - $pageLimit;
```

Comment: braces for multiplication can be omitted

Answer (score 4):

Thought I would add the following for displaying text like e.g:

> Viewing **21-30** of **32** items.

In this example:

```
itemsPerPage = 10
page = 3
totalItems = 32
```

And there would be a total of 4 pages where the last page only has **2** items to display. The following worked for me:

```
(page  - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1 + "-" +
     Math.Min((page - 1) * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage , totalItems ) + " of " +
     totalItems + " items."
```

Sorry that is in C# strictly but the idea should be clear. `Math.Min(x, y)` returns the lower number of two parameters. There is probably an easier solution to calculate the upper bound without using `Math.Min`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple pagination equation that covers all scenerio will be:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

$items_per_page = 20;  //for example

$offset = 0;  //initial offset

if ($page != 1) {
   $offset = ($page * $items_per_page) - $items_per_page;

}
```

Given **items per page = 5**

**OUTPUT**

when **page = 1, offset = 0**

when **page = 2, offset = 5**

when **page = 3, offset = 10**

when **page = 4, offset = 15**
.
.
.

Answer (score 2):

Use following formulae, these work well:

- For `start_index`:  `(page_number - 1) * per_page`
- For `end_index`:    `start_index + (per_page - 1)` (Usually we specify simply `per_page - 1` in SQL)
- 

```
page_number | start_index | end_index | per_page | formula for start_index
    1       |    0        |   24      |    25    |   (page_number - 1) * per_page 
    2       |    25       |   49      |    25    |   (page_number - 1) * per_page 
    3       |    50       |   99      |    25    |   (page_number - 1) * per_page
```

Answer (score 2):

### $offset = $pageNumber * $limit - $limit;

**Page 1:**

```
$pageNumber = 1
$limit = 10
$offset = 1 * 10 - 10 = 0
```

The offset for page 1 is 0, as it is the first page, and there is no need for an offset.

---

**Page 2:**

```
$pageNumber = 2
$limit = 10
$offset = 2 * 10 - 10 = 10
```

The offset for page 2 is 10, as we have already displayed the items from page 1, so we need to skip the first 10 items.

---

**Page 3:**

```
$pageNumber = 3
$limit = 10
$offset = 3 * 10 - 10 = 20
```

The offset for page 3 is 20, as we have already displayed the items from pages 1 and 2, so we need to skip the first 20 items.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$row_page = 5; //items per page

if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $page_num = $_GET['p'];
} else {
    $page_num = 0;
}

$offset = ( $page_num ) * $row_page;

$cn = 31;

$pg = (int)ceil($cn / $row_page);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $pg; $i++){
    echo "<br/><a href='?p=$i'>".$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this before in Angular 4, this is an edit of a piece of template with a list with pagination made simpler:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of pagedItems; let i = index">
  <div class="item-caption">
    Item {{(currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage + (i + 1)}} of {{totalItemsDownloaded}}
  </div>
  <div class="item-name">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I have always handy `currentPage` as a result of clicking on Prev & Next buttons but initialized with 1, `itemsPerPage` as an App setting and `totalItemsDownloaded` is the count of total items the WebAPI call reported.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

following is standard and easiest way to calculate the offset when every page event is triggered.

offset  = ((pageNumber-1) * itemPerPage + 1)-1;

```js
pageNumber = 1
itemPerPage = 10
offset  = ((pageNumber-1) * itemPerPage + 1)-1;
console.log("offset for 1st page", offset)

pageNumber = 2
offset  = ((pageNumber-1) * itemPerPage + 1)-1;
console.log("offset for 2nd page", offset)

pageNumber = 3
offset  = ((pageNumber-1) * itemPerPage + 1)-1;
console.log("offset for 3rd page", offset)
```

Comment: Yes, that is what the accepted answer said

Answer (score 0):

PHP code for setting offset.

```
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit ;
```