# calculating offset based on limit for pagination

Tags: python, pagination

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520996/calculating-item-offset-for-pagination).

I have unknown amount of records to import.
I'm generating GET calls with `offset` and `limit` to import the data as follows:

```
 http://www.myweb.com?WithTotal=true&offset=X&limit=Y
```

`X` is set by loop while `Y` is always the same.

lets assume that Y is 100.

This is what I generate:

```
Generate page: #0     http://www.myweb.com?WithTotal=true&offset=0&limit=100
Generate page: #1     http://www.myweb.com?WithTotal=true&offset=100&limit=100
Generate page: #2     http://www.myweb.com?WithTotal=true&offset=200&limit=100
 ....
```

I'm not sure this is right because some records are missing.

I calculate  as  follows:

```
value_limit = 100
num_of_records = Input from service
num_of_pages = int(math.ceil(num_of_records / value_limit))
pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages)]
for page in pages:
    ....
    value_offset = page * value_limit
    Generate URL
    ....
```

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what records are missing. Is there a pattern in which ones are excluded? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the math.

Comment: @GrantDavidBachman When trying to import 50 pages with limit 100  -  I should have 5000 records. But I have only 4500.   (The total number of available records is 21610 I limit the page numbers for test so I should get 5000 not 4500)